# Silverlight application shows blank screen only

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, silverlight

I am trying to run the [Pluralsight Offline Player](http://pluralsight.com/training/Products/OfflinePlayer) but it shows a blank screen only. The application does not hang, it still reacts on right-click, so I can e.g. access the Silverlight settings. The application is a Silverlight Out-of-Browser application. It used to work for a long time, until ~November 2013.

Uninstalling the application and reinstalling does not help. However, uninstalling Silverlight and reinstalling helps, but I don't want to do this every time I want to run the application. In fact I have already automated this process:

```
@echo off
@echo Uninstalling Silverlight ...
start /w silverlight /qu
:: sleep 5
ping -n 5 -w 1000 localhost >nul
@echo Installing Silverlight ...
start /w silverlight /q
:: sleep 5
ping -n 5 -w 1000 localhost >nul
@echo Starting Pluralsight Offline Player ...
start "Pluralsight Offline Player" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" XXXXX.pluralsight.com
```

Replace XXX by some number assigned during installation of the Pluralsight application. You can find it in C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser

Any ideas how to get the application running without reinstalling Silverlight every time?

System information:

```
Windows 7 Enterprise x64
Silverlight 5.1.20913.0 (the only version on my system)
```

**Update**

It's not a problem of the application, it's a problem of Silverlight. At the time of the blank screen, the Pluralsight DLL is not even loaded yet (checked with WinDbg's `lm` command).

The problem is still reproducable. If you need more information, e.g. call stacks etc. I can probably get it.